# Chrome web app size and position

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm developing a web application for internal use in my company.

The web app will run on Google Chrome and should be packed as a shortcut page or as chrome desktop app, it doesn't matter which one, I will use the one which allow me to get what I need.

My problem currently is find a way to set a default size (and maybe even the position and prevent resizing) of the window of my app.

I can't find solutions to this problem, how should I proceed?

Comment: You can specify a width and height in the background script, as demonstrated here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved with this solution:

https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide

Create a **`manifest.json`** with:

```
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "*://url/app"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://url/app",
      "container": "panel",
      "height": 670,
      "width": 790
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [onLaunched.addListener](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_runtime#event-onLaunched) and create new window with [specific](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-Bounds) width and height:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
        'bounds': {
            'width': 500,
            'height': 500
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: should it works only on packaged chrome applications or even with shortcuts?